# Why doesn't the main thread run to completion when java receives a kill signal?

Tags: java, interrupt, kill-process

So I have this code block:

```
package com.stackoverflow.jontejj.killsignal;
public class Problem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Executing");
            Thread.sleep(1000000);
            System.out.println("Done sleeping");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

}
```

And I'm trying to abort the main method with

```
    kill -15 <pid>
```

And I'm expecting it to print "Interrupted" and a stacktrace, but the program is just killed directly. How should I gracefully handle kill signals?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is documented in [Runtime#addShutdownHook](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)):

> In rare circumstances the virtual machine may abort, that is, stop running without shutting down cleanly. This occurs when the virtual machine is terminated externally, for example with the SIGKILL signal on Unix or the TerminateProcess call on Microsoft Windows. The virtual machine may also abort if a native method goes awry by, for example, corrupting internal data structures or attempting to access nonexistent memory. If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run.

To workaround this behavior and send an interrupt on kill signals, you can do something akin to this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.jontejj.killsignal;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread main = Thread.currentThread();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                main.interrupt();
                main.join(); //Possibly with a timeout here
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000000);
            System.out.println("Done sleeping");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }
}
```

This will result in:

```
Interrupted
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java_stopping/com.stackoverflow.jontejj.killsignal.Solution.main(Solution.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at java_stopping/com.stackoverflow.jontejj.killsignal.Solution.main(Solution.java:14)
```

being printed when a kill signal is received.